# How can I logout an idle user from the Ubuntu GUI desktop using CLI?

Tags: command-line

I am using an Ubuntu GUI desktop and users log in to the desktop via their browser. Using the command `loginctl`, I can get the list of user sessions. But there are some idle users who have not logged out for a long time and their session persists.

Is there a way to determine the idle users (say x minutes of inactivity) and terminate their sessions using the command `loginctl terminate-session <session-id>`?

I have tried understanding the `systemd-logind` service and `logind.conf` file but could not find a proper solution.

`w` or `who` command do not provide the required output.

Comment: How can users login via their browsers? Please give detail on how you made this work.

Comment: I am using an AWS Marketplace AMI which allows this feature

Comment: `sudo loginctl terminate-user username` Kills all processed and all sessions from user.

Comment: Yes, that would be helpful in process and session termination but how do we find out that a particular user is idle for x minutes and then terminate the session.